# Typescript how to access a specific type inside object?

Tags: typescript

I have a type declared like

```
export type BaseExample = {
    type1: {
        somePropA: string,
        somePropB: number,
    },
    type2: {
        somePropA: string,
        somePropB: number,
        somePropC: () => void,
    }
}
```

and then another type written like:

```
export type AdvancedExample = BaseExample & {
    type2: {
        somePropD: string,
        somePropE: number,
    }
}
```

At first it seems to work, but later on I'm trying to create an object that will have type 2 (with somePropA, somePropB, somePropC, somePropD and somePropE).
When I type:

```
const thisElement: AdvancedExample = {}
```

and give it the properties somePropA, somePropB, somePropC, somePropD and somePropE, it just says that "Object literal may onle specify known properties, and somePropC does not exist in type AdvancedExample".

What am I missing? I do believe that i'm having troubles accessing type2 inside AdvancedExample, I just could not figure it out how to do what I intended.

[Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBCBDAzsAoiDAWzABtUBeOAbwCg56FlgBGALmroa6wkOAAUoEMAEF2WGFACWAOwDmAGk5d6PPoOFp2MgK6EARsChKuAXxMMkKAEztaKhmoFDR4ybMXKVTjWC1xdAyMLBx8XAGF2AAoASjhyAD44ADcIKQATELhTGhyaUEhYRhQ4EXTkjBkAY2B0-CJSCnRsPAJiMjgAMg4uK2BbHoc4MOEAETdpeSzuXmdhXG09Q2MvHLyqiBkJOA2tiDIAGQg5eLhY9lSM%20KT7Hc2eMgA6EmOogHIYYAk3mIBuXJoNF22wg%20gAVsAqjBBMBkqdbiNXHA3hJJnI3hZEf5rAAGJTre7wUEQqHsMoVaq1ertJq3R704mQ6FQWGY2a%20BZwZh4ziI8bIjG89kRdjA-bAI6eUxAA)

Comment: Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 
showing the problem.
You can use the [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) to create such an example

Comment: Do you mean that AdvancedExample should only have the property `type2` with somePropA to somePropE? Or do you mean that they should have all of the properties from BaseExample as well as the new ones in AdvancedExample.

Comment: Just updated the question with an example!

Comment: AdvancedExample should only have the property type2 with somePropA to somePropE or have all of the properties from BaseExample if theres a way to get just the "type2" from the AdvancedExample

Comment: You appear to have BaseExample and AdvancedExample that have properties type1 and type2 (each this properties within), yet you are trying to create an object, typed as AdvancedExample, that has sub-properties at the top level.  Also, you are relying on interface merging which only works within the module, but not across modules (which might catch you out later).

Comment: Is this just a typo?  Your object isn't an `AdvancedExample`; it's just the `type2` property of one, i.e., an `AdvancedExample["type2"]`, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wXK69W).  It's the same problem you'd get if you wrote `interface Ex {type2: Date}` and `const x: Ex = new Date()`.  Seems like a category error or something to me.  What can we do here?